# Needed WordPress inbuilt function to resize image

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently, I have added `image_resize` function in my custom API of WordPress for CRON job.
But `image_resize` going to be deprecated. My CRON job is working for around 10000 images. How can I update my code so that deprecation won't hurt my setup? My setup already has ImageMagick and gd libraries.

Below is my current code:

```
image_resize( $srcpath, 60, 60, false,'',$despath,90);
```

Comment: I've edited your post to improve grammar and add an actual question. Please take a look and check if I got you right; if that's not the case, please adjust the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_resize/) it has been replaced by [WP_Image_Editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor/), which has a [`resize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor/resize/) method.

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor($srcpath);
$editor->set_quality(90);
$editor->resize(60, 60, false);
$editor->save($despath);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this function and then regenerate all images using thumbnail regenerate plugin :

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180, true ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in WordPress function then you can use this
    wp_get_image_editor( string $path, array $args = array() )